# apollographql - changes to entries in objects in local state & re-rendering?

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

Let's say I have an object in my local state and 2 types of query on that object: -

`anObject {`

`__typename: "AnObject"`

`thisThing: ""`

`thatThing: ""`
`}`

Query 1

`{`

`anObject @client`

`}`

Query 2

`{`

`anObject @client {`

`thisThing`
`}`

`}`

2 scenarios:-

A component was running Query 1 but does not use anObject.thatThing in it's render function.

A component was running Query 2 (which does not query thatThing).

Now, let's say another component mutated anObject.thatThing. I would assume scenario 1 would cause the component to re-render as it is subscribed to that entire object in the local state (via Query 1) whereas in scenario 2 the component would no re-render if anObject.thatThing mutated as it is only subscribed to a single (different) fragment of that object. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>**You have wrong assumptions.**</del>

Standard `Query` is not a `Subscription` or an `ObservableQuery` - it's an one time query, it won't force automatic update/refetch/render on external changes.

You can use the options listed above or [the simplest] `pollInterval` option.

For deeper object updates you should use `shouldComponentUpdate` method.

---

**UPDATE**

`@client` directive changes default querying behaviour. From docs:

> Once you call client.writeData, the query result on the render prop function will automatically update.

**It may look like a subscription but it isn't.** Query is refetched in both cases. Rerendering of child component depends on its props changes. It won't be rerendered if props passed won't change - for the same query result or passing/using only unchanged result fragments (object properties).

Comment: The `anObject` example above was my client session object. I have an entry in there `isAuthed`. I ran `client.writeData()` to update `isAuthed` from an `onClick()` handler from true to false and the entire app updated accordingly. Perhaps Query is a subscription when using the @client directive?

Comment: So if I change an entry in the object - but one not used by query on that object (as with Query 2 above) then will it re-render components using Query 2? In my real-world example with `isAuthed`... I also have the user's name etc stored in the session object in the local state. I am only querying `isAuthed` in a certain query for conditional rendering of "login", "logout" etc.

Comment: `<Login isAuthed={data.sessionObj.isAuthed} />` will rerender only for this prop (isAuthed) change, not for `data.sessionObj.name` - no matter if `name` is used in query - child component doesn't depend on it.

Comment: What about this scenario (not passing props)? `<Query query={SESSION_ISAUTHED}>
          {({ data }) => {
            return(
              {data.session.isAuthed ? <div>Authed</div> : <div>Is authed</div
   )
          }}
        </Query>`

Comment: It will be entire `data` (query result) object ref dependent ... and stateless functional components ... always render.